# Snowflake odbc log files are not being created

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

We've installed the SnowflakeDSIIDriver version 2.22.00.00 on our Windows server, and established the settings in the Windows registry that theoretically should allow logs to be created.  However, none are being created.  Rebooted the server after configuration as well.
The driver seems to be working just fine, so no issues there.. just trying to troubleshoot a UTF-8 issues and hoping the logs will help.

Thoughts?

Settings in the registry are:
CURLVerboseMode:  true
LogLevel: 6
LogPath: c:\Users\Public\Snowflake ODBC Drive\log

This is on the following box:

OS Name:  Microsoft Windows Server 2016 Datacenter
OS Version: 10.0.14393 N/A  Build 14393

Comment: Have you made the change for HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Snowflake\Driver registry?

Comment: Hi FKayani, we did make, what I believe to be, the corrent registry edits.  The edits made were: CURLVerboseMode: true, LogLevel: 6, and setting a LogPath.

Comment: Can you maybe post a screenshot of the registry settings for Snowflake driver?